# How does IntelliJ Run APIs Locally without Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, tomcat

When I run a Spring Boot Java sample application locally in IntelliJ, how does it run the APIs in Localhost eg 8080 (GET, POST, etc)  ? I don't even have Tomcat installed on my desktop. Trying to understand the internals of "Run Application" Deployment.

[image]

Update: I keep reading "embedded Tomcat", however when I google it, I don't get a clear definition of what this means, and how it differs from Regular Tomcat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Regular Tomcat" means that you launch the Tomcat bootstrap which in turn loads the main Tomcat classes, configures the Tomcat instance and starts the connection listeners.

"Embeded Tomcat" means that you launch a different application (Spring Boot or something else) and that application loads the Tomcat classes, configures the Tomcat instance and starts the connection listeners.

From the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/architecture/startup.html):

> [...] There are several different ways to start tomcat, including:
>
> - From the command line.
> - From a Java program as an embedded server.
> - Automatically as a Windows service.

In the end, configuring and running a Tomcat instance is creating some Java objects, set properties on them and execute some methods on them. Whether Tomcat classes to this for you according to some configuration files or Spring Boot does this for you according to some Spring Boot configuration doesn't make a difference.

Comment: "If Tomcat classes *do* this for you..."

Answer (score 1):

In short, running your Spring Boot application is how it works. The Spring Boot framework is managing the details of instantiating a servlet container--by default, an embedded version of Tomcat--and routing incoming requests to your classes for you. It's not the only servlet container it can use, but most of the time you're not going to care about this detail. That's kind of the point.